# React-Table plus InfiniteScroll implementation not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-table

I'm trying to implement InfiniteScroll using React-Table, I already have all the data in state, so I'm to implement the InfiniteScroll to show the data a bit at a time since we don't want to use pagination, this is what I have so far

```js
<div
  id="scrollableDiv"
  style={{
    height: 320,
    overflow: 'auto',
    display: 'flex',
  }}
>
  <InfiniteScroll
    dataLength={rows.length}
    next={fetchMoreData}
    hasMore={true}
    style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}
    loader={<h4>Loading more items...</h4>}
    scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
  >
...
    <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()} className="table-body">
      {rows.slice(0, offset).map((row) => {
        prepareRow(row);
...
```

My fetchMoreData and offset state are:

```js
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(5);

...

const fetchMoreData = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setOffset(offset + 5);
  }, 100);
};
```

This works the first time, the table gets 5 more rows, but when you reach the end again nothing happens, the `Loading more items` message stays and the `fetchMoreData` function does nothing, what will be the cause for this to work the first time but not after?

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-shadow-3v09i) with similar code, same concept and problem

Comment: sandbox runs without problems. it loads next data set.

Comment: @Apostolos Please check again, as I forgot to save the changes

Comment: @RicardoSanchez where you able to fix this ? I am also facing this problem , after certain number of scrolling down , next is not triggered. My dataset is updating with new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component#readme)
for `next` function

> a function which must be called after reaching the bottom. It must
> trigger some sort of action which fetches the next data. The data is
> passed as children to the InfiniteScroll component and the data should
> contain previous items too. e.g. Initial data = [1, 2, 3] and then
> next load of data should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].

so your `fetchMoreData` function

```
  fetchMoreData = () => {
    if (this.state.items.length >= 500) {
      this.setState({ hasMore: false });
      return;
    }
    // a fake async api call like which sends
    // 20 more records in .5 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        offset: this.state.offset + 5
      });
    }, 500);
  };
```

doesnt increase somehow the original array of items but rather it sets the offset, that's why it keeps saying "Loading". If you push some new items inside your `this.state.items` array, it will work.